# I'm making a GUI program in python that needs to run as root right from the get go, how should I go about it?

Tags: python, root

I was thinking of calling GKSu but I understand it's deprecated. How else can I do this?

Comment: Cross-posted: http://askubuntu.com/questions/857122/im-making-a-python-gui-program-that-needs-to-be-run-as-root-right-from-the-get

Comment: @muru - it's been removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rethink your application. It shouldn't be running the GUI as root. It should just get root for the things it needs to do as root. This is what `gksudo` is for. You should run as non-root, but launch `gksudo blah blah` in a subprocess when you need to do `blah blah` as root.